# Push Notification using Countly API from Salesforce/Apex

Tags: api, salesforce, apex, countly-analytics

I want to implement push notification using Countly API in salesforce can anyone help me with it or provide any guide, I have read all about it on contly's official website but I don't get it completely.
If there is any help article or anything you guys can share that will be appreciated.

I have run the Push countly API using postman by passing some args, but I want to implement it inside my salesforce class so how can I do this.?